# How to keep standing water our of old cement pond/fountain

Tags: outdoor, cover, pond, mosquitoes, fountain

We are renting a property that has an empty cement pond/waterfall feature in the front yard. Its about 5 feet wide and a 1.5 feet deep. Removing the pond is not an option. My concern is standing water in the pond that attracts mosquitos/pests. I'm looking for a easy solution to TEMPORARILY cover or fill the pond that won't do any damage to keep water from collecting in it that isn't ugly like a typical waterproof tarp. I don't want it to detract from the look of the front yard. I was wondering if a big piece of slate/stone that is fit to cover it would work? If so, who would I hire to do that? I'm clueless with yard maintenance. This is our first house with a proper front yard. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I don't think we can guess what you think would detract from the look of the yard. A big piece of stone is heavy enough that you'd need professionals to place it and remove it, so I don't think that is a viable option.

Comment: Have you thought about a little(maybe 12 volt) sump pump to drain it.  It would be hidden and can take it with you after.

Comment: Place some goldfish in the pond. They eat the mosquito larvas

Comment: Just use some mosquito dunks.  They're not expensive.

Comment: drill a hole to drain it

Answer (score 1):

Mosquitoes are a health hazard.

You should tell your landlord about the issue.

If they are unwilling to do anything, call the local health department. They take these things seriously.  It is possible that the Health Dept. will send someone to treat the issue. They may even make it something that is done on a regular basis.  Depending on their protocol, they may direct the property owner to treat the water.

There are [granules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0001AUF8G) that can be put in water to kill larvae. But open standing water is still going to attract mosquitoes.

The best solution is to have the fountain working again.  Moving water will not attract mosquitoes.

Answer (score 0):

Fill it and/or put hole(s) in the bottom.( Both is best ). Smaller holes will tend to partly plug with leaves and yard debris.

Comment: It is not OP's pond/water feature.  Holes would probably be a no-no.